# Hg + Eclipse - filtering changesets for transplant

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, cherry-pick, mercurial-revsets

The action I'm repeating over and over is [transplanting](http://javaforge.com/wiki/76412#section-Transplant) my changes from `default` to production branch. However, each time this means a tedious and error prone task of hand picking the changesets I want to transplant between plethora of other changesets.

[image: Transplant Wizard]

Is there any way of filtering available chagnesets by author and message?

Comment: Good question, I'm afraid I don't know about MercurialEclipse. But you can filter your changesets using a [revset query](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) with TortoiseHg — you can use TortoiseHg for just some operations even though you use MercurialEclipse for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screen shot, no.  It looks like you can't.  As a commenter mentioned, you can use the command line or TortoiseHG to query using a [revset query](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets):

```
hg log -r "user('vartec') and desc('needle')"
```

In Tortoise HG, click the "Search" icon (the magnifying glass) and enter the revset query in the search box.